# Get four random items from array in Jinja

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, filter, jinja2

## Objective

- Show four random golf courses out of the total list of roughly 100 courses in the array if `content.featured == "featured`.
- The key data that needs to switch are `{{content.name}}`, which is the name of the golf course and the hyphenated slug name `{{content.slug}}`.

I've tried using the random filter from this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472403/generating-random-id-from-list-jinja), but I only seem to be getting the first letter of the course name. Without the filter, I just get the first four courses in the array.

## index.html

```
<div class="explore__courses">
            {% for content in COPY.courses if content.featured == "Featured" %}
            {% if loop.index <= 4 %}
            <div class="explore__course">

                <a href="{{ COPY.content.project_url }}/courses/{{ content.slug }}/"><p class="explore__name">{{ content.name|random }}</p></a>
                <p class="explore__distance">tk-miles</p>
                <a href="{{ COPY.content.project_url }}/courses/{{ content.slug }}/"><img src="{{ COPY.content.cdn_url }}/courses/{{content.slug|random}}/{{content.slug|random}}-1.jpg" class="explore__image"></a>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div> <!-- .explore__courses -->
```

## Sample course data

```
var locations = [

        {
            "name": "Aberdeen",
            "slug": "aberdeen",
            "lat": "38.533695",
            "lng": "-90.619151",
            "address": "4111 Crescent Rd, Eureka, MO 63025",
            "state": "MO",
            "holes": "18"
        },

        {
            "name": "Acorns",
            "slug": "acorns",
            "lat": "38.294035",
            "lng": "-90.199375",
            "address": "3933 Ahne Rd, Waterloo, IL 62298",
            "state": "IL",
            "holes": "18"
        },

        {
            "name": "American Legion",
            "slug": "american-legion",
            "lat": "38.803961",
            "lng": "-89.965593",
            "address": "58 IL-157, Edwardsville, IL 62025",
            "state": "IL",
            "holes": "9 "
        },

        {
            "name": "Annbriar",
            "slug": "annbriar",
            "lat": "38.349734",
            "lng": "-90.203934",
            "address": "1524 Birdie Ln, Waterloo, IL 62298",
            "state": "IL",
            "holes": "18"
        },

        {
            "name": "Arlington",
            "slug": "arlington",
            "lat": "38.7079279",
            "lng": "-90.0379311",
            "address": "200 Arlington Dr, Granite City, IL 62040",
            "state": "IL",
            "holes": "18"
        },

        {
            "name": "Ballwin",
            "slug": "ballwin",
            "lat": "38.605788",
            "lng": "-90.538963",
            "address": "333 Holloway Rd, Ballwin, MO 63011",
            "state": "MO",
            "holes": "9 "
        },

        {
            "name": "Bear Creek",
            "slug": "bear-creek",
            "lat": "38.817943",
            "lng": "-90.896974",
            "address": "158 Bear Creek Dr, Wentzville, MO 63385",
            "state": "MO",
            "holes": "18"
        },

        {
            "name": "Bear Creek Valley ",
            "slug": "bear-creek-valley",
            "lat": "38.153609",
            "lng": "-92.600756",
            "address": "910 MO-42, Osage Beach, MO 65065",
            "state": "MO",
            "holes": "18"
        },
];
```

Comment: Do you have to do this in jinja?  Can you make the random selection in your back end and then pass the resulting 4 items to jinja already prepared?

Comment: There's definitely a Jinja trick to solve this, but what @coralvanda is suggesting is by far the cleanest solution

Comment: @coralvanda Optimally, it should be done in Jinja, yes.